# Select several pictures and move them in one go?

Tags: google-photos

Am I correct in understanding that [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/) is unable to let users 1) select a bunch of pictures (through the check mark + CTRL key), and move them all in one go?

It looks like you can only move one picture at a time. Besides, Google Photos is pretty slow.

I tried Picasa, but for some reason, the sort order doesn't match what I see in Google Photos.

Comment: What do you mean by "moving pictures within the same album"?

Answer (score 1):

To select multiple photos, click the arrow icons that are over each photo that you want to select so that they turn blue.

Next click '⋮' in the right hand upper corner then click 'add to' and select the album you want to copy them to. I don't see a move option personally, but you can delete them from the previous album.

Or failing that, try holding down shift then clicking each photo that you want to select.

Comment: Thanks but I need to move pictures within the same album. It looks like Google Photos can't do that :-/

Comment: Google Drive can. and the pictures will already be in google drive by default. There is a google drive app or drive.google.com

Comment: Thanks. I installed Google Drive for PC, but it doesn't show folders, just pictures. It's too complicated, I give up.

Comment: @user2412: That's important information that should be in your question.